# Major CLS issue - Can´t locate it at all - Core Web Vitals - All Pages effected

Tags: google-search-console, page-speed, core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift

since a few weeks already I am trying to fix my CLS issues. My sitemap contains of 150 single pages in total. All of those 150 pages are affected by BOTH the Mobile and Desktop CLS issue (>0.25 & >0.5).

Taking a look at the Lab Data all pages are good, CLS and performance-wise.
Also, working with the Web Vitals Chrome Plugin it doesn't show me any issues even when interacting for minutes with the site.

Has someone a different approach/way to find CLS issues?

Comment: Since Core Web Vitals are measured when real users visit your site (by CrUX reports), check if location or device of your visitors could have played a role.

Comment: Thanks @Kannan. I have thought of this already before and switched the devices. However, still can't locate the potential issue of the Layout Shifts.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't able to detect the CLS issue using lab tools, then the issue is likely the results of user interactions or device/network combinations that you might be aware are common.

I wrote a guide, [Debugging Web Vitals in the field](https://web.dev/debug-web-vitals-in-the-field/) that explains how to use your analytics tool to detect what could be causing the CLS issue with your field data.

I also gave a talk at Google I/O that covers [how to use this technique with Google Analytics 4](https://youtu.be/xg47r3Y6K8I), which you might also find useful.

I hope that helps!